# Opera User Agent: Opera or OPR?

Tags: browser, opera, user-agent

Most specialized sites mention that Opera user agents all contain the word **'Opera'**.

[This kinda old post](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-user-agent-strings-opera-15-and-beyond/) from an Opera developer mentions the string **'OPR'** instead.

The point is: **my site receives regularly visits from 'OPR' browsers and none from 'Opera'**.

Example this morning:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.42
```

Passing my visitors' UA strings to a couple of online UA analyzers returned the verdict that 'OPR' is plain Chrome.

**Can anyone confirm whether real Opera browsers have 'Opera' in their user agent?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Opera/ Opera uses `Opera`. But that's only for versions until 12.
According to the official homepage ( https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-user-agent-strings-opera-15-and-beyond/ ), version 15 and up uses `OPR`.

So I would regex for both, `Opera` and `OPR`

Comment: I see what you mean.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser#Opera_2013 - thank you.